# How to adjust screening (frequency and angle) using Ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript

I have an EPS file that contains c, m, y and k 4 channels.
I try to use Ghostscript ps command to separate it to 4 1bit tiff images.

I don't have any idea about screening function in gs command .

Does anyone known how to adjust screening in gs command?
How to set 1 bit tiff's frequency(lpi) and angle for each separation color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean you have an EPS file, not an ESP file. If so then the EPS program should not contain any halftoning information.

You can use the -c "..." -f sequence to send PostScript directly to Ghostscript, or write PostScript into a file to be processed before your EPS file.

You will find that halftone screening is covered in considerable depth in the PostScript Language Reference Manual, Section 7.4 on page 494 onwards. You can use the old setscreen (one halftone screen only), setcolorscreen (one halftone per plane, Gray, CMYK or RGB) or sethalftone which allows considerably more flexibility.

See also the -dCOLORSCREEN switch described [here](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/Use.htm)

Comment: great! It works very well. 
But I still have 2 questions.
My dot setting -> /SpotDot { 180 mul cos exch 180 mul cos add 2 div } def
1.How to change halftoning algorithm? 
2.Why? The separated 1bit tiffs have a lot of black points in white area.
Thanks

Comment: To alter the halftone spot shape, you will need to alter the PostScript program (which you quoted) which generates the spot shape. I imagine that your original file has a lot of 'not quite white' areas. Trying to fiddle with the halftone is not a good way to deal with that. Much better to apply a transfer function to clamp 'nearly white' to 'white'.

Comment: Thanks KenS, But My EPS is quite white.

Comment: Hi KenS, Finally I found. for example: resoluation 300 and frequency lower than 18 will occur this issue(a lot of black points in white area).

Comment: I'd need an example file and configuration to look at, but that's a pretty coarse screen.

Comment: Hi KenS, resolution 2400 and frequency 133 also. Could I send EPS file and configuration file to you? where?

Comment: No you can't send them. You can place it somewhere I can pick it up and stick a URL here. I'm going to be travelling for the next few days so it may be next week before I have any time to look at this.

Comment: Hi KenS, Thanks for helping me.   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rgjlg68iicbwtx6/AAAsmArOHraUzZhuIr6rRbi8a?dl=0

Comment: I've picked up the files but I am unlikely to be able to look at this until next week.